# Usage of "allein auch"

Tags: usage

What is the difference between
"**Allein auch** in die menschliche Gemeinschaft tritt die natürliche Schwäche hindernd und störend ein"
versus
"**Allein** in die menschliche Gemeinschaft tritt die natürliche Schwäche hindernd und störend ein".
The last sentence is easy to understand. 
What is the added meaning of "**auch**" in this context?

Answer (score 2):

"**Allein**" - Solely, only

"**Allein auch**" - In addition, also, not only

The *auch* implies that *not only* the "natürliche Schwäche" enters the "menschliche Gemeinschaft" but *also* something else (not specified in your excerpt but implied).

Answer (score 1):

"Allein in die etc." means solely, only (tantum).  "Allein auch etc." points out that "die natürliche Schwäche" *also* enters the brotherhood of man.